# Why is capitalized property name not giving an error in Objective-C / UITouch?

Tags: objective-c, properties, capitalization

`resultLabel` is a `UILabel`.  So why does

```
 resultLabel.Text= @"";
```

not give an error?  It should be `resultLabel.text`.

Thanks for any insights.

Comment: good question, when i do that it highlights it as if it were a function, quite strange...

Comment: Probably just because the compiler is fairly intelligent. Unless you happen to have a function or something called Text, it will just assume you meant "text".

Comment: How is resultLabel.Text declared?

Comment: @MarkBernstein OP said it's a regular UILabel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default setter function for a property `foo` is `setFoo:`, with the first letter capitalized. Therefore both lines

```
resultLabel.text = @"";
resultLabel.Text = @"";
```

generate the same code

```
[resultLabel setText:@""];
```

This works only with the setter function, not with the getter:

```
NSString *x = self.text; // --> x = [self text]
NSString *x = self.Text; // --> x = [self Text]
```

As a consequence, you cannot have two read-write properties that differ only in the case of the first letter, this will generate a compiler error:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *text;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *Text;

self.text = @"foo";
// error: synthesized properties 'text' and 'Text' both claim setter 'setText:'
```

Comment: Now can we use  InitWithString:, AddObjectAtIndex: ?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya: initWithString, etc are not properties, so that will not work.

Comment: At first blush it looks like Objective-C is being inconsistently case-insensitive.  [I only noticed it because a student wrote .Text and Xcode approved.]  Thanks for the explanation!

Comment: @MichaelRogers: I would not say that Obj-C is generally case-insensitive. But with properties and even more in Key-Value Coding, certain meanings are associated with method names, and that is a source of ambiguity.

Comment: It is a bug in the compiler.  Please file it.