# iOS 8.3 SDK changes in enforcing property declaration and case sensitivity

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Prior to 8.3, this snipped of code was living (unbeknownst to me of course) in the code base I'm working on

```
NSNumberFormatter *nf = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
nf.NumberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
```

Now, checking the class reference shows that the property's name is actually

```
nf.numberStyle
```

But for some reason this was compiling in 8.2, and not in 8.3. I'm also seeing the 8.3 is forcing me to use `@dynamic` to override a superclass's property setter. I know that I SHOULD do this, and I will make the change, but it worked in 8.2.

There are a lot of these errors in my code base. I've looked over the [release notes](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/releasenotes/General/RN-iOSSDK-8.3/index.html) and haven't seen Apple document either of these changes to the SDK anywhere. Am I missing some documentation? Is there a more exhaustive list of everything Apple has changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a great question. Maybe the way the compiler handles `@properties` has changed in 8.3. This post has a good explanation for why the first letter of the setter of a property was not case sensitive before: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15411523/171933

Basically it seems as if `foo.bar = 1` and `foo.Bar = 1` where both turned into `[foo setBar:1]`. So it worked for setters, but not for getters.

Seemingly this behavior changed in 8.3.

Comment: Is this the kind of thing that Apple documents anywhere, or are we left to just figure it out?

Comment: I guess we are just left to figure it out :)